# How can I send date object from Adobe Flex to RESTful rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, air, rest

I'm working on an Adobe AIR project that use the Ruby on Rails as RESTful web service as the back end.

I have found a lot of examples that show how can I send the data to operated by Rails. but I stuck at date object, which will be very useful if I can send Actionscript's date object to Rails via XML or whatever and Rails can understand the this easier.

Thank you for any answer, I sure that many still find the same solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) library. It has a class called `DateUtil`. 'DateUtil' allows you to translate to and from the Rails W3C date format.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with Rails but some ideas:

- AMF [rubyamf](http://code.google.com/p/rubyamf/)
- JSON [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) has JSON encode/decode